# RxJS 5.5 error: take is not a function. Issue with chained functions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular5

I'm reading about introduction of [*lettable/pipeable* functions in RxJS](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44), but nowhere does it state that this is potentially a breaking change for chained methods. This caught me out in one of our scipts where it started throwing an error after the upgrade:

```
let things = new BehaviorSubject<Thing[]>([]);
things.filter((things) => things.length > 0).take(1).subscribe( ... )
```

> ERROR TypeError: tasks.filter(...).take is not a function

Could somebody explain / point out an article explaining why this is happening? Btw, the fix was to wrap `take(1)` in `pipe()` function:

```
things.filter((things) => things.length > 0).pipe(take(1)).subscribe( ... )
```

..but I'm not sure why am forced to do this all of a sudden.

Comment: take a look at https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Comment: It's interesting that wrapping the `take()` fixes the error related to `filter()`

Comment: Just tried it with the latest @angular/cli@1.5.2. The older import syntax `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'` still works.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 5 supports RxJS 5.5, which introduced *lettable operators* that should help to the tree-shaking process to remove unused code during app bundling. You can import operators from 'rxjs/operators' and then wrap them into a function `pipe()` that takes a variable number of parameters, for example:

```
import { debounceTime, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
...
let keyupValue$ = keyup$
  .pipe(
     debounceTime(500),
     map(event => event['target'].value))
  .subscribe(val => this.doSomething(val));
```

I liked the older syntax better. I don't think it's a breaking change though. You can keep using the older syntax if you won't use import from 'rxjs/operators'.